# Why these Canonical and Hreflang Tags Produce Errors?

Tags: html, seo, multilingual, canonical-link, hreflang

I am working on a website that has Turkish, English, German and French versions. The tags in the head part of the Turkish main page are as follows:

```
<link rel=canonical href='https://www.example.com/tr'/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=tr href="https://www.example.com/tr/"/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=en href="https://www.example.com/en/"/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=x-default href="https://www.example.com/en"/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=de href="https://www.example.com/de/"/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=fr href="https://www.example.com/fr/"/>
```

These tags cause the "Pages with hreflang elements" and "Missing return links" errors when audited via SEO software.

---

The same tags for the French page are:

```
<link rel=canonical href="https://www.example.com/fr"/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=tr href="https://www.example.com/tr"/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=en href="https://www.example.com/en"/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=x-default href="https://www.example.com/en"/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=de href="https://www.example.com/de"/>
<link rel=alternate hreflang=fr href="https://www.example.com/fr"/>
```

There are links to every other language version on every page, for example on the French page:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/tr" hreflang=tr>
<a href="https://www.example.com/en" hreflang=en>
<a href="https://www.example.com/de" hreflang=de>
```

Is there anything wrong in this structure?

Comment: I ahve removed the hreflang=x-default entries and also alternate links which are equal to the canonical. Now, somehow google's pagespeed insight tool doesnot calculate seo score. I am about to go nuts. Somebody please help!

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `x-default` wrong

Your `x-default` should not point to your English page.  Instead it should point to a page for users to choose their language or get redirected to the appropriate language. If you are going to use it, it should probably be `<link rel=alternate hreflang=x-default href="https://www.example.com/"/>`.  See [Introducing `x-default hreflang` for international landing pages  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried removing x-default but I continue to get the same errors.

Comment: You need to give Google a couple weeks after making any changes. It has to recall your pages

Comment: It is not google that prompts teh errors, it is the SEO audit tools. I may share the link to the actual website if you like.

Comment: There are a lot of really bad SEO audit tools out there. So yeah I can take a look but your tool may just have problems

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue: As the remove_quotes filter of mod_pagepeed module removed the quotes of the tags, tools could not read the rel and hreflang values.

It works fine after disabling the filter.

Comment: Are you not using HTML5?  It should be fine to remove the quotes in HTML5.